# How to rearrange array sequently (not by keys)

Tags: php, arrays

```
[4]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(3) "sad"
["element2"]=>
string(1) "2"
 }
 [1]=>
 array(2) {
   ["element1"]=>
string(3) "dsvdv"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "56"
  }
 [2]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(9) "xasx"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "60"
}
[0]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(16) "wqdwqa"
["element2"]=>
string(3) "100"
}
[3]=>
array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(10) "vcsdvds"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "23"
 }
}
```

i was just wondering if is there any way we can rearrange the keys of the array above according to sequence like

```
[0] => first array
[1] => second array and so on.
```

i just want to change the keys not the content , no php array function seemed useful for this issue.

according to the sequence of the codes , i would like to change the keys of array 
that is the template i wish to have.

```
[0]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(3) "sad"
["element2"]=>
string(1) "2"
 }
 [1]=>
 array(2) {
   ["element1"]=>
string(3) "dsvdv"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "56"
  }
 [2]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(9) "xasx"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "60"
}
[3]=>
 array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(16) "wqdwqa"
["element2"]=>
string(3) "100"
}
[4]=>
array(2) {
["element1"]=>
string(10) "vcsdvds"
["element2"]=>
string(2) "23"
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: to be honest i couldn't move my hand , don't have any idea about how to get the sequence of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit confused about what you actually want. If you just want to reindex the array, use

`$newArray = array_values($array);`

If you want to sort the array by key, use

`ksort($array);`

Comment: not by values , by the sequence. first array gets 0 then 1 then 2

Comment: so use the first option

Comment: that returns the same array not changing the indexed [4] key to [0] ?

Comment: It does not return the same array. It reindexes, in the same order as you have presented, starting at 0 (and yes, it changes the 4 to a 0 as per your example)